# Graphing certain columns that includes date and run-time

Tags: python, pandas, date, graph, data-processing

I need help with graphing the data file (tab seperated .csv file) I have which includes many columns and rows.

I only need the 1st and 10th columns to graph. First (index 0) column is for X-axis which holds the dates and 10th column (index 9) holds the run-times I am trying to graph for Y axis.

I read the date values them, shape and sort them in a way that I want them to be, then when I print, it prints only with column names on each line and 0 for all the row indexes. I believe I have the problem with loop, but not sure how to fix it. I try to get rid of the 0 that is assigned as index to each row and keep the column names only on the first row to refer to the columns.

I also tried to plot the dates corresponding to the run-times but my tries were unsuccessful due to the index number being accepted as an argument. The following is what I have tried so far:

```
# Function to process the data files            
def file_processing (file_name):

    # reads the file using pandas and appends them in dict by rows' index numbers and times
    data_file=pandas.read_csv(file_name, sep="\t")
    for row in data_file.itertuples(index=False, name=False, ):
        datetime_obj = datetime.strptime(row[0],'%Y%m%dT%H%M%S')
        datetime_obj = datetime_obj.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

        lst = [datetime_obj]
        lst2 = [row[9]]

        df = pandas.DataFrame(list(zip(lst,lst2)),columns = ['Dates','RunTime'])
        df.sort_values(by=['Dates'])
        print(df)
        #print(df)

        pandas.DataFrame.plot('Dates','Runtime',)
```

My sample data is as follows:

```
20190601T034207 NAME    cc130.aa.bb NAME-7600816.2005   1   1   NAME-37x161 37x161  d39c13  2821    0   0ce000  1283 JOBS/NAME-7600816.2005/blast-37-161.txt
20190601T034214 NAME    cc128.aa.bb NAME-7600816.2004   1   1   NAME-37x161 37x161  d39c13  2815    0   0ce000  1283 JOBS/NAME-7600816.2004/blast-37-161.txt
20190601T034208 NAME    nn019.aa.bb NAME-7600816.2008   1   1   NAME-37x161 37x161  d39c13  3465    0   0ce000  1283 JOBS/NAME-7600816.2008/blast-37-161.txt
20190601T034220 NAME    nn058.aa.bb NAME-7600816.2010   1   1   NAME-37x161 37x161  d39c13  3462    0   0ce000  1283 JOBS/NAME-7600816.2010/blast-37-161.txt
20190601T034217 NAME    nn011.aa.bb NAME-7600816.2014   1   1   NAME-37x161 37x161  d39c13  3469    0   0ce000  1283 JOBS/NAME-7600816.2014/blast-37-161.txt
20190601T034219 NAME    nn224.aa.bb NAME-7600816.2015   1   1   NAME-37x161 37x161  d39c13  3468    0   0ce000  1283 JOBS/NAME-7600816.2015/blast-37-161.txt
```

The results I am getting after running the program after commenting out the code for graphing:

```
                 Dates  RunTime
0  2019-06-01 03:42:14     2815
                 Dates  RunTime
0  2019-06-01 03:42:08     3465
                 Dates  RunTime
0  2019-06-01 03:42:20     3462
                 Dates  RunTime
0  2019-06-01 03:42:17     3469
                 Dates  RunTime
0  2019-06-01 03:42:19     3468
```

Please, let me know if I need to update any part of my question without downgrading it. I would really appreciate it. I am open to any suggestions.
Thanks a lot!

## **UPDATE**

After @MaMaG 's comment, I fixed the code and got a working code. Right now, I am trying to be able to fit all the date labels in X-axis.

#### Working Code

```
def file_processing (file_name):

    data_file = pandas.read_csv(file_name, delim_whitespace=True, header=None)
    data_file.rename(columns={0: 'date', 9:'run_time'}, inplace=True)
    data_file.sort_values(by='date',inplace=True)

    data_file['run_date'] = pandas.to_datetime(data_file.date, format='%Y%m%dT%H%M%S').dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    data_file.plot('run_date', 'run_time')
    plt.show()
```

### Current Graph

[Current Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzUya.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just want to say, first of all, that one of the huge features of a pandas data frame is that you get to apply a single operation to all rows in one line, without doing a time-consuming for loop!

Here's maybe closer to what you want:

```
data_file = pandas.read_csv('../stack_data.csv', delim_whitespace=True, header=None)
data_file['run_date'] = pandas.to_datetime(data_file[0], format='%Y%m%dT%H%M%S').dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
data_file.rename(columns={9: 'run_time'}, inplace=True)
data_file.plot('run_date', 'run_time')
plt.show()
```

No loops, no treating each row one at a time. No need to treat each row as a tuple or use zip. The x-axis dates are probably overlapping each other, but I'm sure if you look into the documentation, you'll find a way to slant them. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the quick help, @MaMaG
I have tried it and updated in my post. It is working. Problem I am having right now is that it shows two figures. One empty, one with data graphed. I am not sure why I have two figures showing. I will try to figure that out myself. 

But main problem right now is to adjust it so I can show all the data at once but be able to fit all the dates in the X-axis as label.

Comment: If you are running that code in a ipython notebook then you don't need the plt.show(). Just delete it.

Comment: I am running it on Linux environment using python project.py. That's why I have to use plt.show(). Otherwise, it does not show the resulted graph

Comment: Do you know any way I can use bokeh in this progran? It would be really helpful to use that tool since There are a lot of date items for X-axis. I would like something like this. It doesn't have to be bokeh, since importing the library gives me an error, but I would like to do something like this to do the hovering: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#formatting-tooltip-fields

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/ticks_and_spines/ticklabels_rotation.html#sphx-glr-gallery-ticks-and-spines-ticklabels-rotation-py

Comment: I found the issue with having two figures, one being empty. I am using ''' plt.plot(data_file.run_date,data_file.run_time) ''' instead of  '''data_file.plot('run_date', 'run_time')'''. Now it only shows one figure. I am looking into how to make X-axis vertical now. Thanks for the help and support!